# Обработка исключения при Inserte

Tags: oracle, sql

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать следущую задачу?

Я пытаюсь занести в таблицу записи таким способом:

```
for rec in (select *
from table 
where ...)
loop
insert into table values rec;
end loop;
```

Как мне сделать, чтобы если попадались повторяющиеся записи, они попадали в exception, а вставка шла дальше по циклу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать проверку на наличии такой строки перед вставкой? Да и зачем вообще `excpetion`? Просто пропускайте строку, и все, если такая уже есть в целевой таблице.

**Обновление**

Как нибудь так:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE ...) THEN CONTINUE;
```

Не знаком с `oracle`, но, думаю, принцип понятен

А зачем вообще вам цикл? Почему не сделать пакетно?

```
INSERT INTO
   destination_table
   (...)
SELECT
   ...
FROM
   source_table
```

**Обновление 2**

[[[[@Sergey4590](/users/8142/sergey4590)](/users/8142/sergey4590)](/users/8142/sergey4590)](/users/8142/sergey4590), а, простите, зачем? Если `destination_table == source_table`, то там и так все записи есть. т.е. все записи попадут, так сказать, в Ваш `exception`. Или я не совсем понимаю, чего Вы хотите добиться. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос.

**Обновление 3**

[[[[@Sergey4590](/users/8142/sergey4590)](/users/8142/sergey4590)](/users/8142/sergey4590)](/users/8142/sergey4590), либо воспользуйтесь вариантом с `EXISTS`, либо погуглите на тему [oracle exception](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=oracle+exception&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: А как мне определять, есть ли она уже в таблице?

Comment: Не понял, что вы имели ввиду. Но я вставляю в ту же таблицу, из которой копирую.